# C# Mysql insert blob

Tags: c#, mysql

i've been trying to insert byte value into Mysql. But with no success. It insert the length of the array instead of the item attributes. Then i need help how do i convert it from blob to readable format

```
string itemsQuery = "INSERT INTO `player_items` (`player_id`, `item_id`, `count`, `attributes`) VALUES ";
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, ItemAttributes);
    byte[] mStream = memoryStream.ToArray();
    string newQuery = string.Format("{0} ({1},{2},{3},{4});", itemsQuery, 1, 1, 1, mStream);
    ExecuteNonQuery(newQuery);
}

string nquery = "SELECT `attributes` FROM `player_items` WHERE " + 1;
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(nquery))
{
    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
}

public int ExecuteNonQuery(string commandText)
{
    int affectedRows = 0;
    using (var connection = mySqlConnection)
    {
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(commandText, connection))
        {
            affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    return affectedRows;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion it to use parameters instead of string concatenation and let the engine do the serialization for you:

```
string itemsQuery = "INSERT INTO `player_items` (`player_id`, `item_id`, `count`, `attributes`) VALUES (@player_id, @item_id, @count, @attributes)";
MySqlParameter[] parameters = {
    new MySqlParameter("player_id",1),
    new MySqlParameter("item_id",1),
    new MySqlParameter("count",1),
    new MySqlParameter("attributes",MySqlDbType.Blob)
    };
parameters[3].Value = ItemAttributes;
ExecuteNonQuery(itemsQuery, parameters);

public int ExecuteNonQuery(string commandText, params MySqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    int affectedRows = 0;
    using (var connection = mySqlConnection)
    {
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(commandText, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    return affectedRows;
}
```

I also notice you seem to be re-using `mySqlConnection` which is a bad idea. Connections are pooled in .NET, so they are relatively cheap to create. The best practice is to create a new `MySqlConnection` in the `using` block rather then re-using an existing one.

Comment: Wow this is just great, and thank you for the feedback about mysqlConnection. This work, but i thougt it would save key and value. What i see in the database inside the blob  is: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String]`

Comment: I was hoping that the parameter would serialize the object value as a blob, but it seems to be defaulting to string. I've changed the parameter to be explicitly a Blob parameter. You may need to play around with the parameter attributes a bit more (`Size`, etc.) but that should get you going.

Comment: Hm i see, but seems it's still the same. I have no idea why. Since the class itself Attributes is serializable

Comment: MySql.Data won't serialize parameter values by default; it will just call `.ToString()` on unrecognised types (which is why you are seeing that data). You will need to convert that object to a `string` or `byte[]`. BTW you should _not_ use `BinaryFormatter`: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/blob/e3e46073005e5f954eaff69de7f96e594edf76ad/tests/protobuf-net.Grpc.Test.Integration/CustomMarshaller.cs#L17-L20